# Dropbox like tray icon behaviour

Tags: .net, winforms

In dropbox when you (right or left) click the tray icon it displays the ContextMenu.
When you double click the tray it executes a method (opens the folder) without showing the contextMenu.
It's possible to make this in .Net?

Answer (score 3):

Yes. Look at the `NotifyIcon` class and implement the `MouseClick` and `DoubleClick` events. To open the context menu strip in your code, see this: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winforms/thread/8de03b21-e144-4614-96cd-d382c2a2fbe9/

Comment: Yes but it doesn't prevent the contextmenustrip from displaying when doubleclick.

Comment: Seems that instead of `MouseDoubleClick` the correct event is `DoubleClick`. Have you looked at this sample in the MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.notifyicon.doubleclick(v=vs.80).aspx. Additionally you could *not* assign the context menu to the notify icon and handle yourself whether it should be opened or not.